# Are there any ways to improve this for loop

Tags: lua

Are there any ways to improve this code?

```
motto = {'What is the motto?', 'Motto', 'Motto', 'Motto' }

for mottoCount=1, #motto do
    print(motto[mottoCount])
end
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'd hardly consider this review worthy, since there's nothing going on and the intent is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Another common idiom uses `ipairs`:

```
for k,v in ipairs(motto) do
    print(v)
end
```